# How to get FK script from existing tables in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

Suppose I have many tables which have Foreign keys created.

I want to get only the scripts for those FKs like so:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT...
```

I've tried to use tools from Studio management, however, it returns the script and create table together. I only want to return the FK scripts.

How can I return only the FK scripts from an SQL table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Management Studio, expand the `Keys` tree of the table you want to script for, right-click the Foreign Key and choose `Script key as...  CREATE` from the menu.